Exploring Electronic Properties: Density of States (DOS) and Band Structure Analysis with Gnuplot?
How can one plot Density of States (DOS) and Band Structure using Gnuplot, and could you provide a sample script to accomplish this task effectively?

This will depend on the format of the output you have. In my case, I use SIESTA for DFT calculations, and I can share some scripts I already used. But DOS and band data should be treated as any other data file.

@Camps thank you for your reply.Kindly share  them i will check them.

I would recommend watching QuantumNerd's videos, where he explains how to calculate and plot using gnuplot the following:

DOS in Quantum Espresso
Band structure in Quantum Espresso . He plots this one not in gnuplot though but plotband.x creates a *.gnu file also which you can plot in gnuplot.

Also Mohan's video, how to plot in gnuplot band structure calculated in Quantum Espresso
See also these pages from the Computational Materials Physics course (also Quantum Espresso):

DOS
Band structure

A large collection of Gnuplot examples: link
If you don't insist on gnuplot then I show how to plot DOS and band structure calculated in VASP using Julia here: link1 , link2
